# Как в флекс сетке сделать один блок выше других, что бы следующие блоки шли после него с ним на уровне, а не под ним

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

по дизайну надо сделать что бы один блок растягивался на 2 ряда, а остальные были одинаковой высоты. Я не понимаю как сделать их во 2 ряд, а не под самый высокий элемент[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.seans-menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 24px;
  
  

  &__link{
    @include reset-link;
  }

  &__item{
    width: 416px;
    height: 258px;
    background-image: url('../img/seans-bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;

    &_one{
      width: 416px;
      height: 540px;
      background-image: url('../img/seans-bg.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
  }


  &__title{
    @include reset-model;
  }

}
```

```html
<section class="seans">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="seans__title title__section">Сеансы RitmStyle</h2>
        <div class="seans-menu">
          <a href="#" class="seans-menu__link">
            <div class="seans-menu__item_one">
              <h3 class="seans-menu__title">
                Стандартный RitmStyle
              </h3>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="seans-menu__link">
            <div class="seans-menu__item">
              <h3 class="seans-menu__title">
                RitmStyle для пар
              </h3>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="seans-menu__link">
            <div class="seans-menu__item">
              <h3 class="seans-menu__title">
                RitmStyle с полным погружением под воду
              </h3>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="seans-menu__link">
            <div class="seans-menu__item">
              <h3 class="seans-menu__title">
                RitmStyle для беременных
              </h3>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="seans-menu__link">
            <div class="seans-menu__item">
              <h3 class="seans-menu__title">
                RitmStyle + красочная подводная фотосессия
              </h3>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить использовать grid-template-areas, у меня получился вот такой вариант. Вы сами можете настроить расположение блоков.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;  /* будет 3 колонки одной ширины */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 150px); /* будет 3 строки высотой 150пх */
  grid-template-areas:  /* сколько ячеек будет занимать какой либо див, точка - это пустые ячейки */
    "item1 item2 item3" 
    "item1 item4 item5";  
}
.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
  background-color: purple; /* вместо цвета можно поставить background-image: url(''); */
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
  background-color: gray;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
  background-color: pink;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: item4;
  background-color: #bada55;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: item5;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
```

```html
<section class="seans">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="item1">
          <h2 class="seans__title title__section">Сеансы RitmStyle</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
          <h3 class="seans__title title__section">RitmStyle для пар</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
          <h3 class="seans__title title__section">RitmStyle с полным погружением под воду</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
          <h3 class="seans__title title__section">RitmStyle для беременных</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item5">
          <h3 class="seans__title title__section">RitmStyle + красочная подводная фотосессия</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Можете, также ознакомиться с такой сеткой подробнее [link](https://doka.guide/css/grid-template-areas/)